# How to write function in postgresql to get months starting date and end date on the basis of name of the month passed to it

Tags: postgresql

I have a scenario where i need to pass name of the month and get the starting and end date of that month.(e.g -> if user selects January it should return 01/01/2019 and 31/01/2019.

I able to get current month's start and end date.

current month's Start date -

```
select date(date_trunc('month', current_date))
```

Current month's end date -

```
select date(date_trunc('month', current_date) + interval '1 month - 1 day');
```

I want a function in postgresql which can return month's starting date and end date on the basis of name of the month passed to it.

Comment: If the user selects "January", which year you want to get? The current?

Comment: @S-Man Yes, I want for current year. The month is selection field in my case so, whichever month user selects it should return that month's starting and end date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=9a8660a044e7a42a164132b2403fcb35)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_month_start_and_end(_month text) 
RETURNS TABLE (start_date date, end_date date) 
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY
    SELECT 
        _start_date,
        (_start_date + interval '1 month -1 day')::date
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            to_date(_month || date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE), 'MonthYYYY') AS _start_date
    ) s;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

1. Get current year: `date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)`
2. Get date from month and year: `to_date(<month text> || <year from 1.>, 'MonthYYYY')`. This gives the first of month because no day value is given
3. Calculate the end day of month as you already described
4. Give out the two columns